# Two C# naming conventions: What do you think?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have two *specific* C# coding conventions I've been practicing with mixed feelings. 
I'd be curious to hear what people think. They are:

**#1. Name instances after the class it's an instance of, camelCased**

**#2: "Matching property names"**

Here's the rationale:

**#1. Name instances after the class it's an instance of, camelCased**

I use this as my default setting for naming convention. Of course, there are exceptions. But used consistently it *dramatically* improves code clarity and maintainability. The code looks like this:

```
var dataConnection = new DataConnection();
//not: var dataConn, dbConn, sqlConn, myDbPickOfTheDay etc.

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();

Timer timer = new Timer(); 

//etc.
```

I'm at the point where code like this causes me physical pain:

```
DataConnection dbConn = new DataConnection();
```

I can't stress enough how this convention has taken away the pain and anger of the variable name game.

This convention is in sharp contrast to attempting to name things in ways that try to indicate what the instance is doing, which amounts to trying to creatively embed the business case in code. Code has a way of getting refactored to the point where those original names are misleading at best.

To me this convention is gold. It also prevents the horrible practice of slightly tweaked variable names for the same thing.

An example of this convention in practice is:

```
class Person { ...
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

//and then
var person = new Person();
person.FirstName = firstName; //where firstName comes from somewhere else.
```

Very easy to read. Very boring. Boring is good when it comes to maintaining code.

*However*, this convention leads me to #2:

**#2 "Matching property names"** ( for lack of a better title )

Here's an example:

```
public class ShoppingCart { ..
  private Item item;
  public Item Item {  //<---- ?
  get { return this.item; } ...
```

The compiler is perfectly happy with this. And, in fact, it exposes a very nice interface:

```
//notice how tempting it is to just say "ShoppingCart cart ... "
ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();  
shoppingCart.Item = item;
```

Now, the alternative is to be creative -- You actually need to drum up two good variable names for Item: the public property name and the private member variable name.

How many times have you seen this and just want to retire immediately?

```
 public class ShoppingCart { ..
      private Item cartItem;
      public Item ShoppingCartItem { 
      get { return this.cartItem; } ..
  ///....
  ShoppingCart userShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
  userShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItem = userSelection;
```

I feel strongly enough about convention #1 that I think I can live with #2.

What do you think ?

Comment: So you really never have pieces of code that have more than one instance of a given type in it? I find that hard to believe. They way you describe your #1 is probably more strict than you mean. Also, C# has a naming standard document, as is already mentioned. I'm tempted to -1 this question, but I'll just leave it.

Comment: I've read and re-read the standard document - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx
It's a great reference and I use it. I don't, however, see any advice on convention for instance names, which leave much to the imagination (think of 3rd parties delivering code). So this is all within the standard coding guidelines, not a counter suggestion.

Clearly, there are cases with more than one instance of a given type. This is more by way of default/rule of thumb.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I really honestly dislike this convention. Semantically, its just as if you asked for the variables to be called a,b,c,d etc (yes, I am exaggerating... a bit). The TYPE you get from the IDE. A FileInfo instance should be called inputFile, outputFile, logFile or whateverTheHellThisFileIsFor.

If I looked at a code following this convention strictly, I'd think that either its a decompiled code, or the developer wanted his code to be as obscure as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in case you were not aware and if you care , C# already has a naming standard

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx

Also, looking at your conventions again ... here's some more suggestions.

- fileInfo looks pretty next to FileInfo but it has no meaning other than it's type which I can quickly get by mousing over the type or in intellisense. I would suggest naming your variables with meaning and some context if available. remoteWebServerLog, localWebServerLog, or even localWebServerLogFileInfo if you like the type in the name.

  If I can hand off any advice from coming back to code you've written 6+ mos later. You will be scratching your head trying to figure out and track down what the heck all your dbConn and fileInfo's are. What file? What db? Lots of apps have several dbs, is this dbConn to the OrdersDB or the ShoppingCartDB?
- Class naming should be more descriptive. Wwould prefer ShoppingCartItem over Item. If every ListBox, DropDown etc named their collection items "Item" you'd be colliding with a lot of namespaces and would be forced to litter your code with MyNameSpace.ShoppingCart.Item.

Having said all that ... even after years of coding I still screw up and don't follow the rules 100% of the time. I might have even used FileInfo fi =  ... but that is why I love my Resharper "Refactor->Rename" command and I use it often.

Comment: IDesign has a good one too:
http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx

Also interesting as a guideline to C# is Mono's Coding Guidelines:
http://mono-project.com/Coding_Guidelines

Maybe they should both pull theirs since MS offers one? ;)

Comment: It makes sense to the follow the Microsoft standard for C# - since you're building on top of a Framework that's already following that standard, your code won't look out of place.
All that said, naming variables so that they add readability makes more sense than FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you can't name every System.String in your project *string*,* but for things you don't use a lot of, esp. things you only need one of, and whose function *in your code* is obvious from its name, these naming conventions are perfectly acceptable.

They're what I do, anyway.

I would go with a more specific name for, say, the Timer object. What's it a timer for?
But I would definitely name a DataConnection dataConnection.

*Even if "string" wasn't a keyword...

Answer (score 2):

Convention #1 can become confusing.  If you were to have two `FileInfo` objects in the same method-- say a Source and a Target-- you'd need to deviate from the convention in order to name the two.

Variable names should be mnemonic-- to indicate to the casual observer the intent of its use.

Perhaps you'd be happiest with a combination of the two conventions... such as sourceFileInfo and targetFileInfo, per this example.

Answer (score 0):

I do 1 all the time and find it very readable.  I'm on the fence with 2.  I find it confusing in certain situations, mainly because it's hard to distinguish the type from the property due to the identifiers being identical.

Comment: I normally don't find that it makes it confusing to tell between the class and the property, because syntax highlighting as well as the context normally show which you are working with.  It can become confusing if there are static members on the class because you get both in the intellisense list.

Answer (score 0):

I follow convention 1 all the time. Although, I do add an additional qualifier if there are two objects side by side.

But having said that, making this convention mandatory may be problematic:

1. In a certain context `cart` may be a good enough name for a `ShoppingCart` object (if, for example, there is no other 'cart' in the same function to be confused with).
2. Sometimes the convention may completely obscure the purpose of the declared object. For example `Window scoreBoard = new Window()` says that we have an object which is indeed a Window but is being used as a scoreBoard. Very expressive.  But following convention 1 you'd have to write `Window window = new Window()` which totally hides the intention behind this window.

So I'd say use this naming idea everywhere except when it hinders meaning or appears unreasonably demanding.

About convention 2, I totally agree. Keeping property names succinct and letting the object name complete the full meaning of its invocation is an elegant thing. It works perfectly with well named objects. So there's little reason to be shy of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally follow convention #1, although for long class names I tend to just use the initials of the class.  If I am referring to more than one object of the same type then I would pre-pend the type name with a name indicating which one it is or what it’s used for.

I quite often use convention #2 if it makes sense.  There is nothing worse than having something like the example you listed of cart.ShopingCartItem, the very fact that it is a property of ShoppingCart makes that part of the property name totally redundant.  However I would quite likely name the class ShoppingCartItem and the property Item.  Item is a little too generic a name whereas ShoppingCartItem tells you what kind of item you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly dislike the notion of having multiple identifiers in scope which differ only in their usage of upper/lower case; if I had my druthers, code which used an identifier would be required to use the same combination of upper/lowercase letters as its declaration, but code would neither be allowed to declare two identifiers in the same scope which differ only by case, nor access any identifier which would--except for case--match an identifier in an inner scope.  Although no language I know of (certainly not VB nor C#) enforces such rules, code written in compliance with such rules could be freely portable between case-sensitive and non-case-sensitive languages without having to rename identifiers.

Consequently, I dislike the pattern #2.  CLS compliance requires that any identifiers of that style be restricted to `private` or `internal` scope.  Since both vb.net and C# allow names to start with underscores, if a property is named `Trait`, I see no reason to favor `trait` over `_trait`.  Use of the latter name would clearly distinguish cases when the programmer wanted to write to the backing variable from those where his finger slipped on the shift key.

As for pattern #1, in cases where the whole purpose of a type or method resolves around a single encapsulated object of some particular type, I prefer to prefix fields with `my` or parameters with `the`.  Even in cases where the compiler would allow the same names to be used for instance members and parameters, using distinct prefixes avoids the possibility of accidentally using one where the other is required.